# What merchant service is best for international transfers?

Tags: paypal

I would like to know the best way for me as a business owner / developer to use the PayPal API to transfer funds from my PayPal account / bank account to a customer's PayPal account.

I was using Stripe, but just as I launched my business, I found out that Stripe cannot perform international transfers of funds under any circumstances. If I have an international customer / user that I owe a portion of funds to, what is the best way to send them these funds using the PayPal API?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Payouts API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/) you can request access to

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look through this.